# How to force email into queue?

Tags: postfix

I'm writing an application for Linux, and it needs to interact with the mail queue. Is there any way to force a message to be deferred?

Comment: have you looked into default_destination_rate_delay? or even changing postfix smtpd to execute sleep?

Comment: I'm from my mobile, have you tried with something like this? postsuper -H QUEUEID

Comment: Perfect! I think combining both of your answers will bring me to where I need to be. - does one of you want to put that as the answer?

Comment: @ZackMagee - you can write up what you did as the A as well, assuming neither of the other users mind. You can make it a detailed A using specifics that you used which will likely make for a very nice A to a Q I'm sure others would appreciate down the road.

Comment: I wasn't aware I could do that! Will do, thank you very much.